# Named pipes async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, named-pipes

Im trying to set up a named pipe server and client to send data between two programs.
My issue is that when i data is recived eg. BeginRead command om server triggers after i have serialized an object from the client it triggers the callback like 20 times for the same message. The goal is that the client program will send commands to the server program. And when the server processes tasks it will send status updates back to the client when there is one connected.

Here is my current test program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new PipeServer();
        server.Init();

        var client = new PipeClient();
        if (client.Connect())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to server.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection failed.");
            return;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(" \\> ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;

            var arr = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int value = 0;

            if (arr.Length != 2) break;
            if (!int.TryParse(arr[1], out value)) break;

            var obj = new PipeObject { Name = arr[0], Value = value };
            client.Send(obj);

            //string result = f.Deserialize(client) as string;
            //Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}

internal class PipeServer
{
    IFormatter Formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    public NamedPipeServerStream Instance { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsConnected { get; internal set; }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65535];
    public object Message { get; set; }

    StreamReader sr;
    StreamWriter sw;

    internal PipeServer()
    {
        IsConnected = false;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        var ps = new PipeSecurity();
        ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
        ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

        Instance = new NamedPipeServerStream("Levscan4Pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 65535, 65535, ps);

        sr = new StreamReader(Instance);
        sw = new StreamWriter(Instance);

        Instance.BeginWaitForConnection(OnClientConnected, Instance);

        Thread t = new Thread(Run);
        t.Start();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        int index = 0;
        if (IsConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                Instance.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, OnRead_Completed, Instance);
                //index += Instance.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                //try
                //{
                //    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                //    {
                //        Message = Formatter.Deserialize(ms);
                //        index = 0;
                //    }
                //}
                //catch (Exception e)
                //{
                //    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                //    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                //}
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                IsConnected = false;
                Instance.Disconnect();
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        //Instance.WaitForConnection();
        //Thread t = new Thread(Run);
        //t.Start();
    }

    void OnClientConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Instance.EndWaitForConnection(ar);
        IsConnected = true;
    }

    void OnRead_Completed(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var bytes = Instance.EndRead(ar);
        Debug.WriteLine("{1} > Read completed - bytes read: {0}".FormatWith(bytes, DateTime.Now.ToString()));

        //try
        //{
        //    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        //    {
        //        Message = Formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        //    }
        //}
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        //    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        //}
    }
}

internal class PipeClient
{
    IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
    public NamedPipeClientStream Instance { get; internal set; }
    StreamWriter sw;
    StreamReader sr;

    public PipeClient()
    {
        Instance = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "Levscan4Pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough);
        sr = new StreamReader(Instance);
        sw = new StreamWriter(Instance);
    }

    public bool Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            Instance.Connect(5000);
            Instance.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
            Instance.WaitForPipeDrain();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Send(object obj)
    {
        f.Serialize(Instance, obj);
        Instance.Flush();
        Instance.WaitForPipeDrain();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Changed the while loop to a if, to start the BeginRead. This solves the multiple callbacks but i stil dont get a complete message.

Comment: I' suggest you read the documentation. For example, calling `Read` on a stream returns the number of bytes that were read. It looks like you assume you will read your whole message in one read which won't necessarily be the case.

Comment: I get the number of bytes read on my callback, but i cant get the total number of bytes of the message. Length and position is not supported on my NamedPipeServerStream object.

Also figured out that i cannot use a while(IsConnected) and everytime call BeginRead function that caused my callback to run multiple times at the same time.

Comment: if i serialize my object to a memorystream and then get the bytes from that and send them all as with the pipestreams Write method i get the message direct in my callback and it works. Why wont serialize direct with my pipestream get the same result ?

Comment: This might be a lot easier if you kick over to WCF with netNamedPipebindings.  (unless you really want to be doing the low-level development).

Answer (score 1):

If the server is writing to the stream like:

```
write field 1
write field 2
write field 3
etc.
```

There is some time between the writes, and the receiver (your program) can be reading the first three fields while the server is still writing the others. The pipe stream doesn't know when the server is finished writing, so it can't buffer everything and send it to you all in one big chunk.

When the server writes everything to a memory stream first and then copies the memory stream to the pipe stream, your program can get it all at once. Maybe. If the server is sending a very large packet, you might read just part of it.

The pipe stream is just a stream of bytes. It doesn't impose any format on the data. It doesn't have any concept of records or anything like that. So you have to treat it like a stream of bytes and do your own composing of records, etc.

If you need to know the size of the record sent from the server, the server has to put that information in the stream for you. Typically, the server will write the length and then the data. The receiver can then read the length, convert it to an integer, and then read that many bytes from the stream. And, yes, it might take multiple reads in order to get all of the bytes. That's just the nature of a byte stream.

The other way to handle this is to have an end-of-record marker. So the server sends its data and your program reads until it finds the byte sequence that signifies the end of the record. You have to be careful, though, because the server could be sending multiple records and your read could grab the end of one record as well as the beginning of the next.

Working with byte streams can be a lot of work because you have to reconstruct records after reading the bytes. It's much easier to use an existing framework (like WCF, as mentioned in one of the comments) if you can.